# Como manipular o objeto retornado por envelope.getResponse()?

Tags: java, android, soap

Estou tendo dificuldade para pegar um objeto que retonar da minha conexão com o servidor, faço o Login e ele me retorna um `getResponse`.

```
  response = envelope.getResponse();
```

Nesse response vem o código do cliente e código das permissões do sistema, como posso manipular e salvar em atributos separados cada um deles? As permissões pode ser em um `array`.

Comment: Resolvi o problema seguindo por aqui. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038165/ksoap2-casting-getresponse

Comment: Rodrigo por que não coloca uma resposta com a solução? Ela poderá no futuro ajudar outras com o mesmo problema.

Comment: @ramaral, acabei de postar a solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue como ficou meu código.

```
public String loginCentral(LoginSerealizable login) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("urn:RouterBoxMobile","LoginCentral");

        SoapObject chaveIntegracao = new SoapObject("urn:RouterBoxMobile","LoginCentral");
        chaveIntegracao.addProperty("ChaveIntegracao",chaveDeIntegracao);


        request.addProperty("Autenticacao",chaveIntegracao);
        request.addProperty("DadosLoginCentral",login);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL_WEBSERVICE);
        httpTransportSE.call("",envelope);

        SoapObject response =(SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        this.codigoCliente = response.getProperty(0).toString();
        this.permissoes = response.getProperty(1).toString();


        return response.toString();
    }
```